# Tutorial on how to import/read a tif/tiff file using java or the java advanced imaging API

Tags: java, import, processing, tiff

I have a tiff image with many directories and subdirectories. I would like to navigate this tiff directory tree and import the image into a 2D array, so I can process this image. I am relatively new to java and cannot figure out how to do this. Will someone please reply to my question with a tutorial and examples of code?

Also, does anyone else find the java API documentation difficult to find, difficult to navigate, and somewhat sparse? I am trying to do this as a workaround for a processing sketch I am creating. Are there different workarounds?

Thank you.

Comment: [What I mean by TIFF directories](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html#Dirs).
Perhaps I should not be using the TIFF format at all. Is there an uncompressed image format that can also store metadata? I have images that correspond to different physical positions and at each position images taken at a fixed rate. These are all currently stored in a giant TIFF file. For each image there is also useful metadata like experimental conditions and time of acquisition.

Comment: TIFF is weirder than I thought..

Comment: why do you need to store all the images in one file?  why not store images as images, and metadata as metadata, e.g. in an xml file?  if you want to stick with the TIFF format with embedded metadata, this seems like it may be a good place to start: http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFDirectory.html

Comment: I think I'm going to try what ericsoco suggests and store my files as PNG with a matching xml file for metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't even know a tiff could have directories and sub directories... But I would have a look in java [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) as a start point to try to see those directories from your app. If you can see them, than you probably can parse them too.